# python array filtering out of bounds

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I tried doing this in python, but I get an error:

```
import numpy as np
array_to_filter = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
equal_array = np.array([1,2,5,5,5])
array_to_filter[equal_array]
```

and this results in:

```
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5
```

What gives? I thought I was doing the right operation here.

I am expecting that if I do

```
array_to_filter[equal_array]
```

That it would return

```
np.array([1,2,5])
```

If I am not on the right track, how would I get it to do that?

Comment: `array_to_filter[equal_array - 1]` maybe this? Index starts from 0.

Answer (score 0):

In the last statement the indices for your array are 1,2,5,5 and 5.  Index 5 refers to 6th element in the array while you have only 5 elements.  `array_to_filter[5]` does not exist.

`[i for i in np.unique(equal_array) if i in array_to_filter]`

would return the answer you want.  This returns each of the unique value in equal_array if it also exist in array_to_filter

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I've edited to specify my real question.

Comment: So this works for this particular case with hard coding values, but what I would like to do is be able to build a function with this that finds the unique values in one array, and returns a match of the unique values in another array.

Comment: you can find unique values in an array by np.unique([list])

Comment: Sure, but now how do I check with these unique values exist in another array?

Answer (score 0):

If `array_to_filter` is guaranteed to have unique values, you can do:

```
>>> array_to_filter[np.in1d(array_to_filter, equal_array)]
array([1, 2, 5])
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html): `np.in1d` can be considered as an element-wise function version of the python keyword `in`, for 1-D sequences. `in1d(a, b)` is roughly equivalent to `np.array([item in b for item in a])`.